# Linux Mint 64 bit eating ram

Tags: linux, linux-mint, memory

I have a Mint 17.1 install.
It has 2x2Gb memory sticks. I have verified this with `sudo dmidecode --type memory`.

My problem is that I don't see all the memory I expect.I would expect 4194304 kB. (i.e. 4*1024*1024). Any idea what I can do to diagnose this problem?

```
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3638260 kB
MemFree:         1597208 kB
Buffers:           96700 kB
Cached:           819392 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           998672 kB
Inactive:         618320 kB
Active(anon):     710036 kB
Inactive(anon):     7988 kB
Active(file):     288636 kB
Inactive(file):   610332 kB
Unevictable:          16 kB
Mlocked:              16 kB
SwapTotal:       3776508 kB
SwapFree:        3776508 kB
Dirty:               276 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        700920 kB
Mapped:           265512 kB
Shmem:             17120 kB
Slab:             105408 kB
SReclaimable:      81308 kB
SUnreclaim:        24100 kB
KernelStack:        2896 kB
PageTables:        26792 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     5595636 kB
Committed_AS:    2326160 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       96544 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359624372 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    122880 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      309032 kB
DirectMap2M:     3469312 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit or 64-bit processor? How about Mint 17.1, is it the 32-bit or 64-bit version? It sounds like you might be hitting the [3GB barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier).

Comment: I am using an E-450 processor which is 64bit. Install is a 64bit edition of Linux and I have run 64bit Windows on this box too.

Comment: See update below.  On a hunch does Windows report 3.85GB for your memory?

Answer (score 0):

I have a 4GB System running Gentoo.  For comparison purposes, here's my output:

```
MemTotal:        4052288 kB
MemFree:          485856 kB
MemAvailable:    1895624 kB
Buffers:          371420 kB
Cached:          1176368 kB
SwapCached:        31280 kB
Active:          2382336 kB
Inactive:         834060 kB
Active(anon):    1323456 kB
Inactive(anon):   423400 kB
Active(file):    1058880 kB
Inactive(file):   410660 kB
Unevictable:         116 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       4001788 kB
SwapFree:        3717076 kB
Dirty:               136 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1656316 kB
Mapped:           396984 kB
Shmem:             78140 kB
Slab:             225388 kB
SReclaimable:     193632 kB
SUnreclaim:        31756 kB
KernelStack:        6000 kB
PageTables:        34952 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     6027932 kB
Committed_AS:    5957536 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      198464 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359519220 kB
AnonHugePages:    116736 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
DirectMap4k:      193408 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
DirectMap2M:     3999744 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

As you can see, it reports over 4GB, so I must agree with OxSheep, and I want to add another possibility.  Make sure your kernel has High Memory Support enabled.  Having it disabled would show the barrier...

---

### Update

As per comments, I hate telling a binary distribution user to "roll their own" kernel after setting the appropriate options, so before we go that route, let's use Mint's update tool.  See Screenshot below:

[image: Update Manager - Level Settings]

I assume you know how to set the level to 5, or use the View > Kernels Menu to select a newer kernel in a safer level?  Attempt to upgrade to a 3.16 version kernel.  After doing so, reboot and rerun the `cat /proc/meminfo` command.  If the results don't change, I have a hunch, but I won't know until I see the results.

Comment: How do I check if I have HighMem enabled? I would expect it would be by default as I am on a 64bit install.

Comment: That's distribution specific, so what is your distribution??

Comment: uname -a
Linux laptop1 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux run The distribution is Rebecca 17.1. Uname details are shown above. Let me know if there is something else you'd like me to run on the command line.